# Do the meanings of statements in both pairs differ?

Tags: present-continuous

> 1. I am being visited by my grandchildren in two weeks.
> 2. I am going to be visited by my grandchildren in two weeks.

and

> 1. The museum is being visited by millions of people next year.
> 2. The museum is going to be visited by millions of people next year.

Answer (score 1):

Practically speaking, these tenses mean the same thing.

> I **am going to be transferred** to the London office next week.
>
> I **am being transferred** to the London office next week.

and

> The London office **is being renovated** next year.
>
> The London office **is going to be renovated** next year.

Answer (score 0):

This present progressive form is not common in daily usage.  When used it more often than not is used for negative emphasis.  "I am being visited by ghosts".

In addition to @Lambie's comments...

1 My grandchildren are visiting in 2 weeks

2 My grandchildren are going to visit in two weeks.

3. In two weeks my grandchildren are visiting.

Comment: The present progressive is pretty common for plans, though, which I think is what the OP was asking about, e.g., "I am going to Italy next month."

Answer (score 0):

The construction of a present progressive verb (e.g. "being visited") plus a future time (e.g. "in two weeks") is a valid English construction indicating a future event. However, it isn't universally equivalent to the future tense used in the second sentence of each pair (e.g. "going to be visited). The first sentence of the second pair sounds very awkward at best.

The distinction I make is that, when making a present progressive statement qualified with a time, it should also be accurate to make that statement *without* the time clause once that time is "now". From the first example that becomes

> I am being visited by my grandchildren

Which is entirely valid and communicates what was expected, that the speaker's grandchildren are currently visiting. On the other hand,

> The museum is being visited by millions of people

while technically valid, the implication there is "millions of *simultaneous* people" rather than "millions of people over the span of 1 year" that the second version indicates. A similar construction which *is* valid might be:

> The museum is being visited by a travelling Van Gogh exhibit next year

While it's possible that the statement isn't true for the entirety of the following year, at some point the exhibit visits and then the statement "The museum is being visited by a travelling Van Gogh exhibit" becomes true, accurate, and has the intended meaning.

In other words, the construction of a statement in the present progressive tense plus a qualifying time means "At the qualifying time, this statement will be true"

Answer (score 0):

Using present tense to express future is not the best choice in English. Both sentences numbered "1" sound awkward.

"to be going to" is a dedicated / known / agreed expression to suggest future, so it is safe. Future tense to express future is the best.